# Induction proof on graph with agents

Tags: graph-theory, induction

I am trying to write simple induction on below Observation, but I am not sure if I am writing it correctly. Thank you for your advice! Note that we can move each agent only once.

**Observation 1**: If we have graph with agents and we move agents in $k$ steps, where $k > 0$ created graph will never be the same as the starting graph. Agents can only move to empty nodes of the graph and there is at least one empty node.

**Proof:**

We proof this by induction. Let us have an assignment $\mathbf{v}$ on initial graph $G_0$ and number of jumps $n$.
We denote agent movement in $i$-th graph as $G_i + jump = G_{i + 1}$.

**Base case:** When $n = 1$, our observation is true as after one jump agent vacates some node in $G_0$ and moves to new node. Following our predefined agent movement we can write this as $G_0 + jump = G_1$.

**Induction step:** Let $k \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and suppose that Observation 1 is true for $n = k$. Then
$$G_{k + 1} = G_{k} + jump$$
$$ G_{k+1} = G_{k - 1} + jump + jump \text{ (by induction hypothesis)}$$

Thus, Observation 1 holds for $n = k + 1$.

**Conclusion: By the principle of induction, Observation 1 is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$.

Comment: You might need to provide more clarifying details. Is this supposed to be true for any graph and any number of agents? EG What if there is only 1 agent and we move them 2 steps -> To the next room and back again?

Comment: Each agent can only move once and we suppose that for $G = (V, E)$ and number of agents, denoted by $r$, where $r < |V|$. I hope this helps to understand.

Comment: If you consider the first agent that moved, what can we say about the room that they moved into, at the very start and at the very end?

Comment: The node/vertex agents move to had to be empty. intuitively, I think that if you move $k$-th agent to empty spot that was created by $k - 1$-th agent then there will be new empty spot created by $k$ agent that was in the starting graph.

Comment: That's at the very start. What about at the very end? Use induction if you must.  $\quad$ Note that your induction proof doesn't work, because simply saying that $G_0$ is different from $G_k$ and $G_k$ is different from $G_{k+1}$, doesn't imply that $G_0$ is different from $G_{k+1}$.

Comment: At the very end we checked each agent movements and then it is similar to what I have written above right? We just ended with $k$-th agent.

Comment: Did you show that $G_0 \neq G_{k+1}$, which is what the question is asking for? I don't see that written down. $\quad$ Note that it is not asking you to show that $G_{k+1} = G_0 + (k+1)$ jumps.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now, thank you very much! :)